# need better PHP script for an if else condition to select current menu item

Tags: php

Using the following PHP script to select the page Im currently on.

each page has the variable $page== 'pagename'

This script works fine but sometimes the buttons need to be rolled over twice in order for the dropdown menu to appear.

Is there a better way?

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul id="nav">
            <!-- If the button HOME is selected then make the HOME Button Active -->
            <?php if ($page == 'home') { ?><li><a href="index.php" a id="current">HOME</a></li>
            <?php } else { ?><li><a href="index.php">HOME</a><?php } ?>

            <!-- If the button ABOUT US is selected then make the ABOUT US Button Active -->
            <?php if ($page == 'about-us') { ?><li><a href="about-us.php" a id="current">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?><li><a href="about-us.php">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>

            <!-- If the page projects is selected then make the Projects Button Active -->
            <?php if ($page == 'projects') { ?><li><a href="projects.php" a id="current">PROJECTS</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="project-01.php">Project 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?><li><a href="projects.php">PROJECTS</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="project-01.php">Project 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>


            <!-- If the page Capabilities is selected then make the Capabilities Button Active -->
            <?php if ($page == 'capabilities') { ?><li><a href="capabilities.php" a id="current">CAPABILITIES</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-civil-works.php">Civil Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-commercial-construction.php">Commercial Construction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-controlled-waste-management.php">Controlled Waste Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-plant-hire.php">Plant Hire</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php } else { ?><li><a href="capabilities.php">CAPABILITIES</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-civil-works.php">Civil Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-commercial-construction.php">Commercial Construction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-controlled-waste-management.php">Controlled Waste Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="capabilities-plant-hire.php">Plant Hire</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>


            <!-- If the page Careers is selected then make the Careers Button Active -->
            <?php if ($page == 'careers') { ?><li><a href="careers.php" a id="current">CAREERS</a></li>
            <?php } else { ?><li><a href="careers.php">CAREERS</a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>

            <!-- If the page Contact Us is selected then make the Contact Us Button Active -->
            <?php if ($page == 'contactus') { ?><li><a href="contact-us.php" a id="current">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <?php } else { ?><li><a href="contact-us.php">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>

        </ul>

        <!-- Search Form -->
        <div class="search-form">
            <form method="get" action="#">
                <input type="text" class="search-text-box" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div> 
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!-- Navigation / End -->
```

Comment: Drop-down menus are done in javascript and/or CSS, not in PHP. What is the js/css code that does the drop-down menus?

Answer (score 0):

The second part could be smaller:

```
        <?php if ($page == 'projects') { ?><li><a href="projects.php" a id="current">PROJECTS</a> <?php } else { ?> <li><a href="projects.php">PROJECTS</a> <?php } ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="project-01.php">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically on which page your are on, that should have `id="current"`? This can be done the following way:

```
<?php
$selected = array($page => ' id="current"');
?>
...
<li><a href="index.php"<?php print $selected['home']; ?>></li>
<li><a href="about-us.php"<?php print $selected['about-us']; ?>>ABOUT US</a></li>
...
```

The array `$selected` will have one index which is the current page and the value will be `id="current"`. So this value will be applied to the active page only.

However this will trigger an [undefined index notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836), but you won't need any `if`s in your code.

If you are okay with a bit more complex structure you could do it like this and won't get notices.

```
<?php
$selected = array($page => ' id="current"');
?>
...
<li><a href="index.php"<?php print isset($selected['home'])?$selected['home']:''; ?>></li>
<li><a href="about-us.php"<?php print isset($selected['about-us'])?$selected['about-us']:''; ?>>ABOUT US</a></li>
...
```

---

Since you are basically doing the same thing over and over again, I'd suggest automating the whole thing anyway.

```
<?php
$naviPages = array(
    array('name' => 'HOME', 'url' => 'index.php'),
    array('name' => 'ABOUT US', 'url' => 'about-us.php'),
    array('name' => 'PROJECTS' => 'url' => 'projects.php', 'children' => array(
        array('name' => 'Project 1', 'url' => 'project-01.php'),
        array('name' => 'Project 2', 'url' => 'project-02.php'),
    )),
    //...
);

//...

foreach ($naviPages as $naviPage) {
    print '<li><a href="'.$naviPage['url'].'"';
    if ($page == $naviPage['name'])
        print ' id="active"';
    print '>'.$naviPage['name'].'</a>';
    if (isset($naviPage['children'])) {
        print '<ul>';
        foreach ($naviPage['children'] as $naviPageChild) {
            print '<li><a href="'.$naviPageChild['url'].'">'.$naviPageChild['name'].'</a></li>';
        }
        print '</ul>';
    }
    print '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to stick the `$page` as a css class in your `<body>` tag or the navigation div. Then you can do just about everything else in pure css!

So for example, say you have this:

```
<div id="navigation" class="page-<?php echo $page ?>">
<ul id="nav">
     <li class="nav-home"><a href="index.php">HOME</a>
     <li class="nav-about"><a href="about-us.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
```

Notice how the navigation div has the page name, and each menu item has a unique class name. Now all you have to do is use some CSS:

```
.page-home .nav-home, 
.page-about .nav-about {
    color: red; /** assuming you want your active/current menu item to be red **/
}
```

See how much cleaner that is?

Of course you can then extend this to show/hiding the sub-menus. Give your sub-menu `<ul>` tag a unique classname:

```
<li class="nav-projects"><a href="projects.php" a id="current">PROJECTS</a>
   <ul class="submenu sub-projects">
      ...
   </ul>
```

And some CSS to control that:

```
.submenu {
    display: none; /** Our default **/
}
.page-projects .sub-projects {
    display: block; /** Show the projects sub-menu when you are on that page **/
}
```